# mongoose: How to access muliple select:false properties while query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my user Schema `password` and `emailVerified` properties are `{select:false}` by default. But I want them while query the user.

What I have tried:

```
 const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select(
    '+emailVerified',
    '+password'
  );
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Invalid select: select only takes 1 argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select( 'emailVerified password' );` or `await User.findOne({ email }).select({ emailVerified: 1,  password: 1 } );`